# How to call a method when binding a TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I would like to Bind() a TextBox in an EditItemTemplate but I need to pass the original value of the textbox to a function before it's displayed. My goal is to format the value before displaying it. It's a complex formatting rule so I can't use any of the built-in formatters. It's easy to do when working with Eval() but with Bind() it's another story. I know it can be done using events in the code-behind but I was trying to do it all from the aspx page.

Example:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" Text=<%# Bind("Name") %> MaxLength="255" runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Thanks...

Comment: I think you're missing single quotes.. `Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'`

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe, I never use quotes in this situation, it's legal. It cuts on the clutter.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Events?

Comment: @rs., I will use an event, but I always try to find shortcuts whenever there might be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be pretty close to what you're looking for:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatValue(Eval("Name"), Container.DisplayItemIndex) %>' />
```

And in the code-behind:

```
public object FormatValue(object value, int itemIndex)
{
    var input = GridView1.Rows[itemIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
    if (input != null)
    {
        //do whatever you need with the old value
        var oldValue = input.Text.Trim();
    }

    //format the value and send it back
    return string.Format("My name is {0}", value);
}
```

Comment: Same comment as rs... You can't use Bind in the context of a function call.

Comment: Eval does not work with two-way databinding.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this from the markup. ASP.NET has a special-case code to parse the `Bind` syntax and generate a special code for it. That's why two-way databinding doesn’t support anything other than `Bind()`. You could find more information on this in the [How ASP.NET databinding deals with Eval() and Bind() statements](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx) article by Eilon Lipton:

> To the surprise of many readers, there isn’t a bind method in ASP.NET!
>   When ASP.NET parses your file and sees you're using a databinding
>   expression (in the angle-bracket-percent-pound format, `"<%# %>"`) it
>   has special-case code to parse for the `Bind` syntax and generates some
>   special code for it. When you use `<%# Bind("Name") %>` it's not a real
>   function call. If ASP.NET parses the code and detects a `Bind()`
>   statement, it splits the statement into two parts. The first part is
>   the one-way databinding portion, which ends up being just a regular
>   `Eval()` call. The second part is the reverse portion, which is
>   typically some code along the lines of `"string name = TextBox1.Text"`
>   that grabs the value back out from where it was bound.
>
> Non-Bind() databinding statements are literal code (we use
>   `CodeSnippetExpressions` in `CodeDom`), so arbitrary code in the language
>   of your choice is allowed. However, because ASP.NET has to parse
>   `Bind()` statements, two-way databinding doesn’t support anything other
>   than `Bind()`. For example, the following syntax is invalid because it
>   tries to invoke arbitrary code and use `Bind()` at the same time:
>   `<%# FormatNameHelper(Bind("Name")) %>` The only formats supported in two-way databinding are `Bind("field")` and `Bind("field", "format string {0}")`.

So, consider to do this in the code-behind, or use `Eval` method instead.

Comment: I was hoping that there could be another syntax of Bind() that would allow me to use it like Eval(), especially since behind the scenes it's an Eval() anyway.