# ASP.NET EditItemTemplate Binding to TimeSpan

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, timespan

I just haven't been able to find the solution after searching existing questions.

Basically, I have a Details View with Editing enabled.  It is bound to a LINQDataSource.  One of the fields is a SQL time, which comes into ASP.NET as a TimeSpan.  I want a 2-way binding.  I already have functions that convert between String and TimeSpan for my purposes.

But here's my conundrum.  I feel like I need one Text= expression to populate the text box when editing begins,

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# TimeSpanToString(Eval("Time")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

but at the same time, a different Text= expression to specify the TimeSpan value to write back to the database on an Update; something like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Time", StringToTimespan(TextBox1.Text) %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

As you can see, I'm very unsure of the syntax to use in the Eval and Bind expressions in the first place, but hopefully I have explained my problem successfully.  There can only be one Text= expression, so obviously something quite different needs to be done here in order to allow the two conversions to take place during data binding and updating.

Thanks!
Sandra

Trying solution from @jadarnel23:

For the ItemTemplate, TimeSpanToTimeString(Eval("Time")) works perfectly.  And also the ItemUpdating function works perfectly - user can enter e.g. 1:30 pm, and it is accepted.

The only problem left is the EditTemplate.

Bind("Time") works, but does not present the user with nicely formatted time.

TimeSpanToString(Eval("Time")) does not work, as you said, because it doesn't create the NewValues entry to work with in ItemUpdating.

And the one that should be the winner, TimeSpanToString(Bind("Time")), actually throws an error on binding "Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'Bind' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."  It looks like I need to elaborate on Bind so that my function can see it, but how?  Thanks, this is really close!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [you cannot call the `Bind` "method" from within another public method in your markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079622/how-to-call-a-method-when-binding-a-textbox/10080320#10080320) (like you can do with `Eval`), it looks like you are stuck doing a normal "Bind" in the `EditItemTemplate`:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("Time") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

*Note: you need to do a `Bind`, because that will make it show up in your ItemUpdating event later, to save it to the database*

Then update it for display purposes as soon as the DetailsView is databound (make sure it's also in Edit Mode):

```
protected void yourDetailsView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (yourDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        TextBox timeTextBox = (TextBox)yourDetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1");
        timeTextBox.Text = TimeSpanToString(timeTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Then, you can handle [the `ItemUpdating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemupdating(v=vs.110).aspx), and manipulate the value of "Time" prior to saving it to the database:

```
protected void yourDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    String newTime = e.NewValues["Time"].ToString();
    e.NewValues["Time"] = StringToTimespan(newTime);
}
```

Notice you can extract the user-entered values from the [`DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsviewupdateeventargs.newvalues(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This sounds brilliant!  I should have time to work on this project today or tomorrow, and look forward to reporting back.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, @Sandra.  I look forward to hearing if it worked for you or not =)

Comment: Hey, @Sandra.  Looks like some of your comment did not come through =)  What's not working?

Comment: Comment too long for comment field.  @jadarnel23, I'm posting my results as an edit to my original question.  Please see above - one remaining facet doesn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sandra Excellent!  Looks like we're making progress.  That is an odd error though.  Does it help to put .ToString() after the Bind call?  Like this: `TimeSpanToString(Bind("Time").ToString())`

Comment: unfortunately, same error.  I think that the TimeSpanToString function doesn't know the Bind function.  Any idea what the namespace of Bind is?  It's not DataBinder like for Eval.

Comment: @Sandra After doing some research on my own, I found out that [you can't embed a call to `Bind` in another function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079622/how-to-call-a-method-when-binding-a-textbox/10080320#10080320) (see the link for awesome details).  I'm going to update my answer with what it looks like you'll need to do.

Comment: Sir, you are brilliant!  Thank you ever so much.

Comment: You're very welcome, @Sandra!  I'm glad I could help =)  Hey, I learned something too.  So it was a win-win haha.